# Combine two JSON objects into one based on keys and retain values

Tags: javascript, npm, lodash

I had the following 2 json objects denoting some data as follows:

```
passObject = 
{
  'Topic One' : 4, 'Topic Two' : 10, 'Topic Three' : 1, 'Topic Four' : 1 
}

failObject = 
{
  'Topic Two' : 3, 'Topic One' : 1 
}
```

I needed to combine the two objects into one to produce the result:

```
resultObject = {
 'topics': [
         { 'Topic One' : { 'pass' : 4, 'fail': 1 } },
         { 'Topic Two' : { 'pass' : 10, 'fail': 3 } },
         { 'Topic Three' : { 'pass' : 1, 'fail': 0 } },
         { 'Topic Four' : { 'pass' : 1, 'fail': 0 } }  
     ]
}
```

I have looked into 'lodash' functions but have not been able to find the necessary functionality. Would someone be able to suggest a way of how it can be done most efficiently ?

Comment: Why do yo even need to represent the result as a list? Won't the names in and of themselves be sufficient? i.e. resultObject = {'Topic One:' {'pass':4, 'fail':1}}.  {'Topic Two:' {'pass':10, 'fail':3}} .... etc etc?

Comment: yes, that might work but this was meant to be an api with a required format. Either case, how could i merge them ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
passObject = 
{
  'Topic One' : 4, 'Topic Two' : 10, 'Topic Three' : 1, 'Topic Four' : 1 
};

failObject = 
{
  'Topic Two' : 3, 'Topic One' : 1 
};
intObject = {}

for (var k in passObject) {
    intObject[k] = {'pass':passObject[k]}
}
for (var k in failObject) {
    intObject[k]['fail'] = failObject[k]
}
document.write('<p>' + JSON.stringify(intObject) + '</p>')

resultObject = {
 'topics': []
}
for (var k in intObject) {
  d = {}
  d[k] = intObject[k]
  resultObject['topics'].push(d)
}
document.write('<p>' + JSON.stringify(resultObject) + '</p>')
```

I started with an object to store key value pairs, and avoid lookup complexities a list would introduce.
I then converted it to a list after so you can meet your API needs.
No need for Lodash. Just simple Javascript.